# Gaussian density function implementation in Keras

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras

I am trying to implement a gaussian density function evaluator function in keras (python). I have tried with the following approach but it is not working

```
def normal(z, mean, var, z_dim):
    return 1/(K.pow(2 * np.pi, z_dim / 2) * K.prod(var, 1)) * K.exp(- 1 / 2 * K.sum(K.square(z - mean) / var, 1))
```

I am getting the following error.

```
 Output tensors to a Model must be Keras tensors. Found: Tensor("mul_2207:0", shape=(?,), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial, it's easy to follow : https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html